# Appdesigner_uitree_my_own_component

Tags: matlab, tree, nodes, matlab-app-designer

Iam new to appbuliding and Iam trying to build dataprocessing app.
But for my app I need uitree sturcute where I can change color oftext in subnode and color of backgroun of subnode. The uitreenode doesnt have this properties.
So dou you know:
How I can create new (my_uitree component) with this properties?
Where I can find how to do it?

Sorry for my trivial guestion, but for me it is hard. I tried lots of I've tried a lot of attempts at this and I still can't do it.

I tried for exampl build html component, but I think that it is imposible with html component. So I think that the only way is to build my own uicomponent.

Comment: It seems to be possible. Take a look at the code [in this question](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1624585-how-to-add-multiple-styles-to-my-uitree)
You can change both the font and background colour using the [uistyle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uistyle.html) and [addStyle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addStyle.html) functions.